# Unable to resolve service for type 'Core.Data.CoreContext' while attempting to activate 'Core.Data.Repositories.UnitOfWork'

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, projects-and-solutions

I have part of WebAPI application that I want to move to separate project as class library.
It is common base structure that almost every app has so idea is to make it easy shareable.
Application type is:
ASP.NET Core Web Application / .NET Framework - ASP.NET Core 2.0 / Web API

What I have done in that direction is created a project named Core and moved those shared elements there, including Base Entities (e.g. User, Settings, etc), CoreContext, UnitOfWork, Generic Repository, BaseRepositories,...

In the Main project of app there are others Entities, AppContext that inherits CoreContext, more Repositories, and all Controllers, ...

I was able to build the app but when starting it get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Core.Data.CoreContext' while attempting to activate 'Core.Data.Repositories.UnitOfWork'.
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type
>   serviceType, Type implementationType, ISet callSiteChain,
>   ParameterInfo[] parameters, bool throwIfCallSiteNotFound)...

Problem seems to be that `UnitOfWork` class is in Core project and in Main project is `Startup.cs` with method `ConfigureServices` that has `services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();`.

Is this a bug or am I just not configuring it correctly and how could it be achieved, if possible at all?

*Further technical details:
NetCore & EF Core version: 2.0
Database Provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
IDE: Visual Studio 2017 15.3
Operating system: Windows 10

UPDATE: Code Sample

```
namespace Main
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>().Build();
    }
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
            services.AddMvc();
            var conn = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"); 
            services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(conn));
        }
    }
}

namespace Main.Data
{
    public class AppContext : CoreContext
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

-

```
namespace Core.Data
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
    {
        public CoreContext context;

        public UnitOfWork(CoreContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public T Get<T>() where T : BaseRepository, new()
        {
            var repository = new T();
            repository.Init(context);
            return repository;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code

Comment: Question Updated with Code sample.

Comment: I understand from your code that you use UnitOfWork to access your repositories and simply it can't be resolved because you need to add it in DI  

`services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();` 
and also you need to inject all your repos

Comment: This is currently in single project App and it works.
What I am trying here now is to move part of code to another project Core within the same Solution so that it can later be easily shared.
The issue is that I moved UnitOfWork to Core but it is still being resolved from Startup that is in Main and there seems to be some problem there.
Repositories are in Core along with UnitOfWork so I think there is No problem with them.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
    where TContext : CoreContext
{
   public UnitOfWork(TContext ctx) { ... }
   ...
}
```

-

```
public class AppUnitOfWork : UnitOfWork<AppContext> { 
    public AppUnitOfWork(AppContext ctx) : base(ctx) { }
}
...
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       ...
        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, AppUnitOfWork>(); // Note the App prefix
        services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(conn)); // Note the App prefix
    }
    ...
}
```

Solution is from GitHub [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2140):